# Locked Camera View

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera, object-mode

I have locked myself into camera view/am restricted to viewing my sculpture from the camera viewport only, and am unable to exit this mode despite following the advice I have found on this subject on YouTube, Google, et al.

So far, I have tried all the known shortcuts used to enter and exit camera view, I have ensured that I have enabled numpad, and the 3-button mouse.

The screenshot I've included below also showcases a circle surrounding my doughnut which, to be perfectly honest, I have no idea as to its purpose.

Since I am new to Blender, I am still very much in the process of learning the ropes, so any help towards rectifying this problem would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: hello, it doesn't look like you are in camera view, as we see your active camera in front of your view, so you're probably in normal viewport view

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thanks for replying to my post. Ah, in that case, I'm really not sure what I've done! It's strange - I can only pan up, down, left and right - I'm prevented from rotating around the sculpture as per when in edit or object mode. All I'm sure of is that my movements are severely restricted. If you could offer any insight as to what I might have done, it'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: You must have switched to another navigation mode but I don't know them so I hope someone will answer